# How to start modeling a square metal profile with holes?

Tags: modeling, extrude

I'm new to Blender (switched over from Sketchup) and I'm struggling with the complexity of the program.

I have no idea how I should start modeling a square metal profile with holes.

Can anyone give me any pointers of how I can start?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can start considering the object symmetries, 8 parts like that:

[image]

Thus, we'll try to make it and use Blender's mirror modifier.

As rounded parts are generally more complex to do, we start with them:

Add a circle, with a relative low resolution (say 16 vertices). This will be the center of the shape.

Then duplicate it in edit mode <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and extrude and scale this last one <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to the wanted value.

Here you should have something like this:

[image]

As this is symmetrical, from the above picture, we can delete the unwanted part. So, only keep this:

[image]

From that, it is only aligning and extruding to be at the dimensions you want:

[image]

Now the mirror modifier part:

We need two mirrors,

- One to make a quarter of the shape: it uses an empty as pivot rotated 45 degrees.
- One to replicate the previous one along X and Y axis.

Here is the setting:

[image]

So we now have:

[image]

Finally, we can add a solidify modifier to extrude the shape:

[image]

Last points:

- Use shade smooth (in object mode <kbd>W</kbd> then *'shade smooth'*)
- And use autosmooth for the normals (look at the image below)

[image]

A blend file with the several steps included:

[image]